# How do I add many videos programmatically into one video?

Tags: c#, ruby, video

I have 1000 videos in MPEG4 H.264 AAC format. They are named `1.mp4`, `2.mp5`, ..., `1000.mp5`. How can I add them programmatically in order into one big video? I suppose I need a video editor that supports a scripting language. I found [AviSynth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AviSynth) which might be a possibility. I would love to hear your suggestions.

(I am on Windows7 or Linux Mint.)

Comment: http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20concatenate%20(join,%20merge)%20media%20files

Comment: @Bogdan you are a hero. If you post this comment as an answer I will accept and give you some upvotes if you happen to care about that. :-)

Comment: I am glad I could help. Had a similar problem once and lost a lot of time until I found ffmpeg :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bogdan provided the following link: http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20concatenate%20(join,%20merge)%20media%20files. This program works like a charm (on Linux).

Answer (score 1):

Probably can be done on Mac using QuickTime Pro and Automator. QuickTime will combine the videos into one. Automator can be used to add all files in a directory into one video in Quicktime.

Comment: Thanks. But I am on Linux / Windows! Will edit question.